# "This post has/had interested me so much that I even took a screenshot."

Tags: tense, sequence-of-tenses

Which sentence is correct?

> This post has interested me so much that I even took a screenshot.

OR

> This post had interested me so much that I even took a screenshot.

Has or had?

Answer (score 1):

"Had" (this is a past tense narrative, so use a past tense)

But as with most cases of the past perfect.  Just avoid it completely:

> This post interested me so much that I took a screenshot.